# Can changing the DNS name of a postfix server damage reputation?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix

I was tasked with taking charge of all services at my current job after the person previously in charge left. Some of our services were using a domain name that's wholly in his possesion, not that of the company. So far, I've managed to change them all to our own domain names, but I'm unsure whether changing the mail ones (postfix, dovecot, etc.) can have any negative effect on our IP reputation. Is this a safe change to perform?

Note that he has been wholly uncooperative before in similar matters, so approaching him on this issue is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to a new domain should not directly affect your IP Reputation, but it is better to "Warm Up" your IP before sending 100% of your email volume.
Twillio has a great guide on the same. That can be found [**here**](https://sendgrid.com/resource/email-guide-ip-warm-up/).

The gist of it is that you should start by sending a small percentage of your emails. From here you should slowly increase the volume of emails. This provides the recipient ISP the time to build a worthwhile reputation on your Domain/IP. Sending many emails from a domain that had no prior activity, will make the recipient ISPs think that it is coming from a spammer. Doing this shows the recipient ISP that the emails are authentic and that their customers actively engage with the email. This is commonly referred to as "Warming Up" an IP or domain.

Comment: Thanks! That's a pretty helpful response. Do you know if I could speed up this process by using mailgun or a similar service? I could send all e-mail through mailgun, but still receive it at the new domain. Could ISPs distrust it because the domain suddenly changed?

Comment: @Haf I wouldn't recommend doing that. But it depends on the ISP if they would trust mailgun or not. I don't have much experience with using mailgun, so I'm not qualified to speak to that. Doing some quick google-ing shows that mailgun themselves have an article on this. That can be found [here](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/deliverability/domain-ip-reputation-gmail-care-more-about/)